# What's the use case of secondary constructors in abstract classes?

Tags: scala, constructor, abstract-class, language-design

Consider this code:

```
abstract class Foo(val s: String) {
  def this(i: Int) = this("" + (i+2))
}
```

As far as I understand constructors aren't inherited and secondary constructors cannot be called from subclasses with `super` like in Java.

Are they just a useless artifact or is there some sensible use-case for this construct?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
scala> object Bar extends Foo(3)
defined module Bar

scala> Bar.s
res3: String = 5
```

Answer (score 11):

The primary constructor of the subclass must call one of the constructor of the superclass, not necessarily the primary one.

```
abstract class A(s: String) {
  def this(i: Int) = this(i.toString)
}
class B(i: Int) extends A(i)
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @coubeatczech's answer, you can also create instances of abstract classes (and traits) if you add a refinement,

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

abstract class Foo(val s: String) {
  def this(i: Int) = this("" + (i+2))
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class Foo

scala> val f = new Foo(23) {}
f: Foo = $anon$1@13d874e

scala> f.s
res3: String = 25
```

Although I've show an empty refinement above ("{}") you would typically provide some additional definitions, often providing implementations for abstract members,

```
scala> abstract class Bar { def bar : Int }
defined trait Bar

scala> val b : Bar = new Bar { def bar = 23 }
b: Bar = $anon$1@1e17c6d

scala> b.bar
res1: Int = 23
```